# Error in forward engineering

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors, syntax-error, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

im having an Issue with 1 of my tables(Manager). To find out whos a senior manager I used 3 tables which is functionally dependent on one and another. Im trying to forward engineer it but im not sure where im going wrong.

The error:

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table
>   'db12401612.MANAGER' (errno: 150)

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `db12401612`.`MANAGER`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db12401612`.`MANAGER` (
      `Manager_ID` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Manager_ID`),
      INDEX `fk_MANANGER_SENIOR INSTRUCTOR1_idx` (`Manager_ID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_MANANGER_SENIOR INSTRUCTOR1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Manager_ID`)
        REFERENCES `db12401612`.`SENIOR INSTRUCTOR` (`Senior_Instructor`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

If I'm doing this wrong can someone correct me, thanks.

I have 3 tables, example

senior instructor 1 to 1, manager and 1 to 1 office

```
SENIOR INSTRUCTOR     MANAGER                 OFFICE
 +----+               +-----------+          +---------------------+  
 | S_id |             | manager_id|         |O_id                  |    
 +----+               +-----------+         |city                  |
                                            |post_code             |
                                            |phone_num             |
                                            |street_name           |
                                            |manager_manager_id    |
                                             +----------------------+
```

Comment: can someone format my code please.

Comment: I suggest you use http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/design/ - It will help you get started fast with correct DDL. Also manager_manager_id is a horribly bad name in my opinion. The same is true for O_id and S_ID.

Comment: okay, ill check it up. They arent the proper name, the names are:

Senior_Instructor and Office_ID, was trying to save time :)